# "in the morning on Sunday" and "on the morning of Sunday"

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Jesse takes the train in the morning on Sunday.

or

> Jesse takes the train in the morning of Sunday.

It looks to me that both are correct. If yes, do they have different connotations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would've been better if you wrote:

> "Jesse takes the train **on Sunday morning**."

[image]

Here's a quick recap on how to use prepositions in case you don't remember it anymore.

Comment: WOW!!!!! Very interesting. Thank you!

Comment: Where did that triangle go? Please, get it back here!

Comment: You don't want your sentence to sound too long and chunky. You're welcome.

Comment: Re-uploaded it for you.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: Your answer changed the meaning of the sentence. The question was asking about a *particular* Sunday morning, but you turned it into a habitual action. You should use the *singular* not the *plural* if you want to preserve the meaning: *Jesse takes the train on Sunday* ***morning.***