# In the early morning OR on the early morning

Tags: prepositions

> **On the early morning of** February 5, arsonists tossed firebombs through the window of Lum's Restaurant.
>
> Convinced of the imminent collapse of his authority, Batista left the
> country **in the early morning of** January 1, 1959

These sentences are from newspapers. Would they remain correct if ON and IN were swapped around?

Comment: We usually use **on** with dates and **in** with times of day. Because these two sentences include both, the issue isn't so clear-cut, and the different journalists have made different choices.

Comment: And because of what Kate said, the first one focuses on the date it happened, while the second one focuses on the time of day it happened.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In the morning VS on the morning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18763/in-the-morning-vs-on-the-morning) Also [in the morning of, on the morning of](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/319512/in-the-morning-of-on-the-morning-of) and perhaps ["in the morning on Sunday" and "on the morning of Sunday"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/204651/in-the-morning-on-sunday-and-on-the-morning-of-sunday)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Kate Bunting's comment:
We usually use on with dates and in with times of day. Because these two sentences include both, the issue isn't so clear-cut, and the different journalists have made different choices.

Because of that, the first sentence focuses on *the date it happened*, while the second one focuses on *the time of day it happened*.

I can imagine the first sentence coming from a police report giving a dry timeline of events, while I can see the second sentence coming from a novel where we experience Batista's flight in the early morning.

So, yes, the sentences would remain correct if "in" and "on" were swapped, but the focus would change.